# Smarty Template Get Value from mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, smarty

I am a database and Smarty newbie. I have a Smarty template where I would like to get a value from mySql database.

My database structure is as follow:

```
MySql
    Mydatabase
        Table1
          username (info stored here)
          usermail  
        Table2
           GroupA
               ID = 101 (a unique number value)
               Age  (a number value)
           GroupB
                ID =102  (a unique number value)
                Age  (a number value)
        Table3
    phpmyadmin
    .....
```

In a Smarty template, I can easily get the username via the following:

```
    {$Table1.username}
```

The value I would like to obtain is Age on Table 2 GroupB. I know the stored value of ID and can use it.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
    {$Table2.GroupB.Age}
```

The logged user has rights to get the values of Table2.

Any ideas? I appreciate any help or advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Smarty first from this `http://www.smarty.net/`

write a php file for database connection and get the values from table.
 Refer:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp
```

then assign the resultset to array, like

PHP file:

```
$smarty->assign('result',$recordset);
```

use the template file which you want to display the database values:

```
$smarty->display('default/presentation.tpl');
```

smarty file:
    {$result|print_r}
you can view the database values.

then using **section** or  **foreach** you can split the array values and display it.

Comment: Thank you Raj... I do appreciate how much I have to learn. The web application already has the connection between Smarty and the database... to the extent I can, on the template, extract infor via the `{$Table1.username}`. What I am trying to extract is info that is 3 layers deep in the db, as opposed to 2. I was hoping for an easy answer... which simply just may not be possible. Thanks again.